# Querying aMember

Tags: mysql, amember

I'm trying to pull a query from aMember. We have a few tables:

```
am_user - Contains user data - PK = user_id
am_invoice - Contains one line per invoice - PK invoice_id, FK to user_id
am_invoice_item - Contains one line per product - FK to invoice_id
```

We currently sell 2 different products using 4 different product_ids (it's software, and the products are translated in 2 different versions). Users can buy only episode 1, only episode 2, or both. (We're not interested in those who did not make a purchase yet).

My query looks like the following:

```
 SELECT 
     u.user_id, login, u.added
    , CASE ii.item_id 
        WHEN 3 THEN i.tm_added 
        WHEN 5 THEN i.tm_added 
        ELSE NULL END AS Episode1Bought
    , CASE ii2.item_id
        WHEN 7 THEN i2.tm_added
        WHEN 6 THEN i2.tm_added
        ELSE NULL END AS Episode2Bought
FROM 
    am_user u 
        LEFT JOIN am_invoice i ON u.user_id = i.user_id
        LEFT JOIN am_invoice_item ii ON i.invoice_id = ii.invoice_id AND ii.item_id IN (3, 5)
        LEFT JOIN am_invoice i2 ON u.user_id = i2.user_id 
        LEFT JOIN am_invoice_item ii2 ON i2.invoice_id = ii2.invoice_id AND ii2.item_id IN (7, 6)
WHERE i.status = 1 AND i2.status = 1 -- Only paid invoices
ORDER BY user_id
```

However, this ends up returning up to 4 rows for customers who bought both episodes. For others, who only bought 1 episode, it works correctly:

```
1   user1   2013-12-07 18:06:01   Episode1_EN   2014-01-11 13:28:19   Episode2_DK   2014-02-15 10:22:30
1   user1   2013-12-07 18:06:01   NULL          NULL                  Episode2_DK   2014-02-15 10:22:30
1   user1   2013-12-07 18:06:01   Episode1_EN   2014-01-11 13:28:19   NULL          NULL    
1   user1   2013-12-07 18:06:01   NULL          NULL                  NULL          NULL
```

I'd like for it to only return the row containing the details for both the purchases:

```
1   user1   2013-12-07 18:06:01   Episode1_EN   2014-01-11 13:28:19   Episode2_DK   2014-02-15 10:22:30
```

I bet I'm overlooking something pretty simple, but for the life of me cannot figure out where I went wrong. Any ideas how I can get rid of the redundant rows?

Comment: Did you try with `inner join`?? And can you post some data or a fiddle?

Comment: @Gone - I did, yeah. Originally had the first `invoice` JOIN as an inner, but that excludes those who only bought episode 2. If I make all JOINs `INNER`, I'd end up only with those customers that bought both episodes, which the resultset I'm looking for should contain all purchasers.

Will try and post a fiddle later, when I'm back at my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by using two separate queries; one for `product1`, and another for `product2`. In the `product1` query, I add a `NUL`L column with an alias of `Episode2Bought`. In the `product2` query, I do the same, but for `Product1Bought`. This way I can `UNION` thw two resultsets.

However, this still lead to duplicate rows in case a user purchased both products. To solve that, I wrap a SELECT around that resultset, use `MAX()` functions on the ProductBought columns to remove the NULLS and use a GROUP BY to merge the duplicate rows together.

The end query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    user_id
    , login
    , added
    , MAX(Episode1Bought) AS Episode1Bought
    , MAX(Episode2Bought) AS Episode2Bought
FROM
(

SELECT 
u.user_id, login, u.added
    , CASE ii.item_id 
        WHEN 3 THEN i.tm_added 
        WHEN 5 THEN i.tm_added 
        ELSE NULL END AS Episode1Bought
    , NULL AS Episode2Bought

FROM 
    am_user u 
        JOIN am_invoice i ON u.user_id = i.user_id
        JOIN am_invoice_item ii ON i.invoice_id = ii.invoice_id AND ((ii.item_id IN (3, 5)) )
    WHERE i.status = 1
UNION  
SELECT 
u.user_id, login, u.added
    , NULL AS Episode1Bought
    , CASE ii.item_id 
        WHEN 6 THEN i.tm_added 
        WHEN 7 THEN i.tm_added 
        ELSE NULL END AS Episode2Bought
FROM 
    am_user u 
        JOIN am_invoice i ON u.user_id = i.user_id
        JOIN am_invoice_item ii ON i.invoice_id = ii.invoice_id AND ((ii.item_id IN (6, 7)) )
    WHERE i.status = 1
)
as a 
GROUP BY user_id, login, added
ORDER BY user_id
;
```

This correctly returns the desired result:

```
1   user1   2013-12-07 18:06:01   Episode1_EN   2014-01-11 13:28:19   Episode2_DK   2014-02-15 10:22:30
```